# Don't understand the simple ResNet from 'Deep Implicit Layers' Tutorial

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network

The Deep Implicit Layers Tutorial is a nice resource that dives into Neural ODEs, Deep Equilibrium Models etc., using the JAX library. In chapter 3 (out of 5), [Link: http://implicit-layers-tutorial.org/neural_odes/] there is the following example ResNet, which I am confused about:

```
import jax.numpy as jnp

def mlp(params, inputs):
  # A multi-layer perceptron, i.e. a fully-connected neural network.
  for w, b in params:
    outputs = jnp.dot(inputs, w) + b  # Linear transform
    inputs = jnp.tanh(outputs)        # Nonlinearity
  return outputs


def resnet(params, inputs, depth):
  for i in range(depth):
    outputs = mlp(params, inputs) + inputs
  return outputs
```

***What is particularly confusing to me is that in the 'resnet' function, the for loop over the depth seems COMPLETELY redundant.***

The inputs of previous layers are not being fed to later layers, and the 'i' index is not being used.

Am I missing some fundamental information about ResNets? Is it a mistake? Can someone explain the point of the for loop?